# cntk.input_variable() v.s. cntk.sequence.input_variable()

Tags: placeholder, cntk

what is the difference between `cntk.input_variable()` and `cntk.sequence.input_variable()`? I want to create some placeholders for the inputs and output, but not sure which one I should use? PS. my CNTK is version 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

`cntk.input_variable` creates an input variable that only has a single dynamic axis (the batch axis). Values passed to this type of input variable should be samples (or minibatches of samples), not sequences. `cntk.sequence.input_variable` creates an input variable with two dynamic axes, a sequence axis and a batch axis. The expected input value for this type of input is an entire sequence (of an arbitrary length).